# How to add version, description, name, etc information to a DLL cross-compiled from C++ in linux?

Tags: dll, g++, mingw, cross-compiling

How do I add all this information to my *C++-Linux-cross-compiled-using-MinGW* DLL?

[image]

I'm creating my DLL cross-compiling C++ code in Linux so **using windows and VS to add this is NOT an option**. All answers I've found so far talk about VS.

Comment: Windows executable and DLL version information is set with [the `VERSIONINFO` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource). You need to create your own resource file (`.rc`) and build with it.

Comment: What is your environment (terminal, IDE, what IDE)? What build-system do you use (`make`, CMake, something else)? if you use an IDE, have you tried just creating the `.rc` file and see how the IDE builds it? For CMake if you list the `.rc` file as a normal source file it will handle it correctly on Windows, perhaps it does it on other systems too? I think `make` have correct implicit rules to build `.rc` files as well.

Comment: Regarding the resource file itself, you have to explicitly create and edit it. Remember the `.rc` suffix.

Comment: @m4l490n nope you use mingw windres to convert the .rc into a .res, then link that with the linker/compiler

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hey this is what I ended up doing and works really well, do you mind adding your comment as an answer to choose it and close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses a special *resource file* to contain information about things like images, dialog templates, and for your use-case, version information.

A resource is just like a source file, so you need to create it with your source code editor. Then add a [`VERSIONINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource) resource in the file, and add the file to your build system.

If you use a system such as CMake it will be able to automatically detect resource files (if named with a `.rc` suffix) and build and link it into the application.